# How can I use XPath to return a node that contains one particular element with particular inner text?

Tags: xpath

Let's say I want to find the `<p>` tag that ONLY contains `<u>***</u>`. What is the XPath query to use for this? I thought I found an answer in `//p[u["..."]]`, but that does not work. This would be much easier if I could do something like `//p[text()="<u>***</u>"]`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `<u>` tag is child of `<p>`, so you can use: "/..". This syntax can select parent node of current node. Your xpath should be:

```
//p/u[text()="<yourtext>"]/..
```

You should refer to [XPath Toturial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) on w3school for more syntax of XPath.

Comment: But will that guarantee a selection of `p` tags that ONLY contain `<u>***</u>`?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot your ONLY.
`//p/u[text()="<yourtext>"]/..[count(*)=1]`
This syntax find the `<p>` that contains `<u>***</u>` and this `<p>` has only 1 child. That mean `<p>` tag that ONLY contains `<u>***</u>`